# DD command running for over 17 hours on external 1.5TB drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, ubuntu-10.04, process, dd, ps

I used `dd` with `nohup` to erase a 1.5TB disk and now I can't get feedback from the progress.. Since it's been more than 17 hours I am worried...

- I ran the command with the disk unmounted.
- The disk is an external backup connected by an external SATA port.
- ubuntu 10.04

**Some info on the process:**

```
$ ps ax | grep dd
1469 ?        D     95:54 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde

$ ps -eo pid,comm,lstart,etime,time,args|grep dd
21469 dd              Mon Jun 22 17:36:07 2015    17:38:47 01:36:02 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde
```

**Should I wait, reboot the system or something else?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a block size for `dd`, so it's writing in 512-byte blocks. That's why it's so slow.

1. Attach running `dd` to some terminal (using, for example, [reptyr](https://serverfault.com/a/272526)). This way you'll be able to read its stdout. You may have to use `sudo` or any other method to run it as root.

   ```
   $ ps aux | grep [d]d
   (take note of PID)
   $ reptyr PID_OF_DD
   ```
2. Send `SIGUSR1` to `dd` — it will report on progress and you'll be able to calculate how much of the drive is already zeroed.

   ```
   kill -s USR1 PID_OF_DD
   ```
3. You can kill `dd` and run it again, this time specifying block size (e.g., `dd bs=4K` for 4K blocks) and offset to avoid overwriting already zeroed space. Use the [seek](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108858/53467) argument to skip as much data as `dd` reports as written.

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde bs=4K seek=NUMBER_OF_4K_BLOCKS_ALREADY_ZEROED
   ```

If you can't reattach `dd` using `reptyr`, but you remember in which directory you ran `dd`, then you can skip step 1. Then in step 2 stats will be written to a file called `nohup.out` in that directory.

Comment: wow, this really is a good answer! My only problem is that for a reason unknown to me the command `reptyr  21469` is not working.. It outputs `[-] Timed out waiting for child stop. Unable to attach to pid 21469: Operation not permitted` ... :-)

Comment: @Luciano Either try with `sudo` or skip step 1 and look for a file called `nohup.out` after step 2 (see my edit)

Comment: damm.. I ran the reptyr as sudo and a lot of options showed.. (I thought they were options but it seems they were a report of what reptyr did..) I think I should have hit `ctrl+z` but instead I did a `ctrl+c` and killed it. Anyway.. after `ctrl_c` it showed the following: `1413427491328 bytes (1.4 TB) copied, 73485.6 s, 19.2 MB/s` .... I was almost there!!! :-(  *Question:* What is the NUMBER_OF_4K_BLOCKS_ALREADY_ZEROED so I can I try dd again ?

Comment: @Luciano It has copied 1413427491328 bytes so far, so almost entire drive is zeroed. 4KB = 4000B. 1413427491328 / 4000 = 353356872 blocks, your command is `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde bs=4K seek=353356872`

Comment: ow, of course... the seek will skip based on the current `bs` parameter.. glad I asked! **It WORKED!** Thanks. Now I did it in a tmux session and can monitor progress with `sudo kill -USR1 $(pgrep ^dd). It is running at ~60 MB/s.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a `bs` (eg.`bs=4k`) parameter. This makes your write speed rather slow, and >17 hours is not unexpected for 1.5TB.

Edit, to (give options to) answer the question:

- waiting will get you there eventually
- rebooting seems an overreaction
- you could just kill the dd process and start it again with a bs parameter, but i'm not sure this will gain you anything, it depends on how far along the current operation is, which is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: Your post is in fact true, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: well, that's up to personal preference.

Comment: The question was "Should I wait, reboot the system or something else?". You have presented correct explanation, but no solution.

Comment: So wait it is? How much longer? If I restart the computer will the drive get damaged?

Comment: @Luciano, you should [have your accounts merged](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can mark accepted answer when you have your solution.